# Is this inequality true

Tags: inequality

Let $a_k, \lambda_k>0$, $k=1, \ldots, n$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k=1$. Is it true $\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_ka_k\right)^2\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k/a_k^2\right)\ge 1$?

Comment: An alternate way is Holder's Inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Generalized mean inequality says

$$\sum \lambda_k a_k \ge \prod a_k^{\lambda_k}$$

and
$$\sum \lambda_k \frac{1}{a_k^2} \ge \prod (\frac{1}{a^2_k})^{\lambda_k}$$